# How to fix error "Ambiguous use of 'increment'" on iOS Firestore increment()

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I receive a compiler error when trying to use firebase `FieldValue.increment(1)` in iOS using swift. The error only says "Ambiguous use of 'increment'"

I have updated all my pods to the current versions of all firebase pods used. More specifically I am on Firebase(5.20.2) and FirebaseFirestore (1.2.1).

My code (below) is almost exactly the same as the example in the docs [Seen at the bottom of this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)

How can I fix this error and get the app to compile?

```swift
let docRef = db.collection("metadata").document("permanentConversions")
docRef.updateData([
        "total": FieldValue.increment(1)
    ])
```

Comment: you need to use `docRef.updateData(["total":firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)])`

Comment: reference your firebase import

Comment: That gives another error "Use of unresolved identifier 'firebase'; did you mean 'FirebaseApp'?" and trying `FirebaseApp.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)` gives the error "Type 'FirebaseApp' has no member 'firestore'"

Comment: hmm..I think the way you did it is good, but not sure why is not working, I would say make sure your imports are good, your initialization of firebase and firestore is good. and also see this link and how they did it: https://github.com/firebase/snippets-ios/blob/master/firestore/swift/firestore-smoketest/ViewController.swift

Comment: My imports look good Im importing `Firebase` and `FirebaseFirestore` have a few other firebase calls in this file and they all work. Interestingly, if I copy over the file you linked I get the exact same error for their example of increment. I'm on xcode Version 10.2.1 - still using swift 4.2 - do you think I need to update to swift 5 for this to work?

Comment: getting the same error. no idea why

Comment: @MichaelMcKenna I also still have the error. I updated my app to Swift 5 and the error is still there. If I find a fix I'll definitely post here - if you do please let me know!

Comment: I have this issue too using the same code as @projectmind.  It does not look like a path problem as using another operator `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` works okay.  Also, the documentation does not suggest this is needed: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters

Comment: The "Ambiguous use of 'increment'" error is solved for me by changing the code to `FieldValue.increment(Int64(1))`.  I guess the problem is a compiler issue with working out whether 1 represents a double or int64.

Comment: yep, not working for me either. going to request the firebase team to fix this. In the meantime use .runTransaction to read the value, change it, then save it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the "Ambiguous use of 'increment'" error is solved for me by changing the code in the example to 
`FieldValue.increment(Int64(1))`.
The compiler provides an option of double or int64 for the increment operator and I guess it does not know which one to choose.