# Why is FieldValue.increment() giving me an error in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

So the only thing I changed was adding:

```
pod 'Geofirestore'
```

to my podfile for my IOS app using Firestore, which had these:

```
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Geofirestore'
  pod 'InstantSearch', '~> 5.0'
```

and suddenly my lines of code updating field values in Firestore are throwing errors. The lines:

```
db.collection("people").document(userID!).updateData(["listsCount": FieldValue.increment(Int64(1))])
```

are now giving me the error:

> Type 'FieldValue' has no member 'increment'

For the life of me I can't figure out what suddenly changed. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is FieldValue also defined in Geofirestore? Try using Firebase.FieldValue.increment.

Comment: Perhaps `Geofirestore` also has a `FieldValue` type, and the compiler picks that one instead of the one you want. Try using the fully qualified name: `ModuleName.TypeIWantToUse` (e.g. `Firebase.FieldValue` if the type in discussion is part of Firebase.

Comment: I don't believe Geofirestore has anything like FieldValue so it's not likely it's being trampled by another library. Additionally Swift is pretty smart that way and knows what calls are expecting. I would suggest cleaning the build folder and re-building your project. (I just added Geofirestore to a project that uses FieldValue and it's working correctly.)

Comment: Having the same problem!

Comment: Perhaps [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55841639/how-to-fix-error-ambiguous-use-of-increment-on-ios-firestore-increment) could help.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this issue by initialising my value as a `Double` before updating the field. This way Firebase knows how to interpret the increment which can either be `Double` or `Int64`

```
   let value: Double = 1

    ref.updateData([
        "likeCount" : FieldValue.increment(value)

    ])
```