# what is the syntax for field value increment Firestore in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to update a field using Field Value increment in firestore

in Android I can use this syntax:

```
FieldValue.increment(1)
```

in the backend, I can use this:

```
admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
```

I have tried to google it, but I can't find the documentation about this increment feature. so I need to know the increment syntax for iOS (swift)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
FieldValue.increment(Int64(1))
```

See the Swift API docs for [FieldValue.increment()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/FieldValue#increment_:) and the [Firebase documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value).

Comment: thank you very much Doug but I think it should be `FieldValue.increment(Int64(1))`  as per the documentation you share https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnMUy.png . otherwise it will give error like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55841639/how-to-fix-error-ambiguous-use-of-increment-on-ios-firestore-increment , maybe it needs to be edited a little bit for other iOS users :)

Comment: Note that FieldValue.increment() will automatically increment by one